# Creating a new thymeleaf template in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, thymeleaf

I am using IntelliJ to make an app that uses thymeleaf but when I click to create a new file there is no option for thymeleaf. I know thymeleaf files are just html, but it seems like there should be a preconfigured option for this?

Comment: Version of Intellij?

Comment: @ShridharR.Kulkarni IntelliJ Ultimate 2017.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Plugin Configuration Wizard to enable Thymeleaf plugin.

You can [manage plugins](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/managing-plugins.html) to enable or disable plugins in intellij.

or

> File -> Other Settings -> Config Plugins -> check thymeleaf.

Don't forget to add `xmlns:th=”http://www.thymeleaf.org”` in HTML root as shown [here](https://smarterco.de/intellij-idea-thymeleaf-namespace-unknown/).

Comment: Thymleaf plugin is enabled but I dont have a menu option for creating a new html file preconfgured with thymeleaf stuff. I guess I can just create my own template :)

Answer (score 0):

1. File -> Other Settings -> Config Plugins -> check thymeleaf.
2. Add dependency in file: `pom.xml`
3. In HTML,don't forget to add   `xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"`

[image]

Comment: I not sure if u have answer the question. I believe what he is asking is whether intellij allow us to add a new thymleaf file that already contains the boilerplate text (such as xmlns:th=....), so that we don't have to type all these manually ourselves.