# IntelliJ (2018.3) with Thymeleaf - NO auto completion on paths to static content?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea, thymeleaf

Code completion for **paths** and **filenames** do NOT seem to work in IntelliJ with Thymeleaf: `th:src="@{...}"` attributes - e.g. files in the `resources/static/` folder.

I'm using the latest version of IntelliJ Ultimate Edition (2018.3.x as I am typing this) with the latest Spring Boot "2.1.3.RELEASE", along with the latest Thymeleaf packages.

I have only one controller class, and one HTML template. Simple stuff. I can run the app fine and the content shows up.

However, auto completion for static resources is **NOT** working when typing in the template - for images, css etc. When using the standard HTML `src=` attribute e.g. `src="../static/images/mylogo.png"` code completion works fine. Paths to static content with Thymeleaf `th:src="@{...}"` tags have no auto completion at all.

[image: Example of static content in the template]

Any suggestions or help would be VERY welcome. I've been using IntelliJ Ultimate for many years, and hopefully this is just a setting I am overlooking. Cannot find anything online pointing at this or a solution. I recall (maybe mistakenly) that this worked a couple years back on a project. Tried on 3 systems and the same behavior. Setting? Config? IntelliJ Bug?

Comment: Did you tried this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43108100/creating-a-new-thymeleaf-template-in-intellij?

Comment: @soorapadman yes of course. I have the Thymeleaf attributes working fine in the template. Code completion is NOT working for **paths and filenames** WHEN using the Thymeleaf `th:src="@{.....}"` attribute.

Comment: Please try https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/web-application-static-content.html

Comment: @MebinJoe I believe that's specifically for how your content is resolved in the container once you deploy/run your app, not necessarily setting up paths that resolve in the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

1. File -> Other Settings -> Config Plugins -> check thymeleaf.
2. Add dependency in file: porm.xml
3. In HTML,don't forget to add `xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"`

[image]

You can see more at here

https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html